Use array of variables as iterative inputs to R function without for loop
I am trying to use an array to feed all the variables into a function, K times.
Here is a simple example:
set.seed(707)

Func<-function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j){
  temp <- a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j
  return(temp)
}

K <- 3
library(lhs)
A <- randomLHS(10,K)

> A
            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
 [1,] 0.71223229 0.62418246 0.3933959
 [2,] 0.01531924 0.06501699 0.7463748
 [3,] 0.85278795 0.19983286 0.1856308
 [4,] 0.28234183 0.32716120 0.6706615
 [5,] 0.11708063 0.74196491 0.8515147
 [6,] 0.33521099 0.45473874 0.9173855
 [7,] 0.97812812 0.57400252 0.4987922
 [8,] 0.53003009 0.94340463 0.0293076
 [9,] 0.49162910 0.84928499 0.2309974
[10,] 0.69963290 0.26794110 0.5024444

I'd like to feed each column to the function Func iteratively, and then combine the results. The best solution I can come up with relies on a for loop and indexing, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this with apply:
Out <- NULL
for(i in 1:K){
test <- do.call(what = Func, args = as.list(A[,i]))
Out <- c(Out,test)
}

To make sure it worked as I think it should, I just compare:
Out
colSums(A)

> Out
[1] 5.014393 5.047530 5.026505
> colSums(A)
[1] 5.014393 5.047530 5.026505


With apply():
Out <- apply(A, 2, FUN = \(x) do.call(Func, args = as.list(x)))

And some performance benchmarks:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
loop = {
Out <- NULL
for(i in 1:K){
  test <- do.call(what = Func, args = as.list(A[,i]))
  Out <- c(Out,test)
}
},
apply = {Out <- apply(A, 2, FUN = \(x) do.call(Func, args = as.list(x)))}
)
#Unit: microseconds
#  expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
#  loop 2465.3 2522.10 2833.954 2625.7 2797.00 13389.8   100
# apply   35.7   39.75   64.778   48.7   53.65  1657.5   100


You could tranpose A and convert using as.data.frame(), and then use purrr::pmap (and its variants, such as pmap_dbl), which will work row-wise
purrr::pmap_dbl(unname(as.data.frame(t(A))), Func)

Output:
[1] 5.014393 5.047530 5.026505


This works on my simple example here, but for some reason it doesn't work on my real problem (Error in purrr::pmap_dbl(): ℹ In index: 1. Caused by error: ! Result must be length 1, not 2.), whereas the apply() example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78405367/9096420) does work in the more complicated situation

I guess you'd need to show some more complicated data.. Happy to try to adjust it, if you want to show some different data.

A comparison, adding vapply sapply and lapply

loop and pre-allocated for loop
[lsv]apply and
purrr::pmap

(extended example to 3000 columns)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval   cld
          loop 159.79808 178.81487 187.87486 182.85090 188.93922 531.71953   100 a    
 loop_prealloc 141.37526 144.90223 154.67211 149.20793 162.05925 258.09861   100  b   
         apply  93.90093  96.06814 104.79287  98.96047 115.81233 148.14640   100   c  
        sapply  51.93582  52.93239  58.99584  53.76213  60.29467 103.02632   100    d 
        lapply  51.00278  51.90525  58.33392  54.32286  59.65481 100.58006   100    d 
        vapply  50.88470  52.33178  56.58569  53.84601  55.85471  75.83976   100    d 
    purrr_pmap  70.30283  71.79129  80.33837  74.27282  88.91068 230.69388   100     e


library(microbenchmark)

plt <- microbenchmark(
loop = {
K <- 3000
Out <- NULL
for(i in 1:K){
  test <- do.call(what = Func, args = as.list(df[,i]))
  Out <- c(Out,test)
}
},
loop_prealloc = {
K <- 3000
Out <- rep(numeric(0), K)
for(i in 1:K){
  Out[i] <- do.call(what = Func, args = as.list(df[,i]))
}
},
apply = {apply(df, 2, FUN = \(x) do.call(Func, args = as.list(x)))},
sapply = {sapply(df, \(x) do.call(Func, as.list(x)))},
lapply = {lapply(df, \(x) do.call(Func, as.list(x)))},
vapply = {vapply(df, \(x) do.call(Func, as.list(x)), 1)},
purrr_pmap = {purrr::pmap_dbl(unname(as.data.frame(t(df))), Func)}
)

ggplot2::autoplot(plt)

Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0.71223229, 0.01531924, 0.85278795, 0.28234183, 
0.11708063, 0.33521099, 0.97812812, 0.53003009, 0.4916291, 0.6996329
), V2 = c(0.62418246, 0.06501699, 0.19983286, 0.3271612, 0.74196491, 
0.45473874, 0.57400252, 0.94340463, 0.84928499, 0.2679411), V3 = c(0.3933959, 
0.7463748, 0.1856308, 0.6706615, 0.8515147, 0.9173855, 0.4987922, 
0.0293076, 0.2309974, 0.5024444)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df <- data.frame(rep(df, 1000))


I get an error trying to run this code (replacing df with A): Error in (function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) : argument "b" is missing, with no default. Can you share how you generated df?

I think it is df <- as.data.frame(A), which works for me

Yea, sorry, added the data and the plotting command.
